# Lemma Section 8 of Fraleigh

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am working on the Lemma in Fraleigh text on Abstract Algebra 7th edition section 8.

If we let $G$ and $G'$ be groups and define a one to one function $\phi$ that satisfies the homomorphism property, then $\phi[G]$ is a subgroup of $G'$ and $\phi$ provides an isomorphism of $G$ with $\phi[G]$.

What I am confused about is why we need to justify the isomorphism (specifically how proving the subgroup result leads to this conclusion) of $G$ with $\phi[G]$. I feel like it is automatic in the assumptions and the definition of $\phi[G]$.

1. We assume $\phi$ is a one to one function from $G$ to $G'$.
2. Homomorphism is assumed
3. Clearly $\phi$ is onto $\phi[G]$ by definition of an image.

I just figured out that I am correct in everything I wrote above. What we are using in the theorem that follows (Cayley's theorem) is the fact that $\phi[G]$ is a subgroup. Caley's theorem states that every group is isomporphic to a group of permutations. So, we'd like to establish a one to one homomorphism between G and some group of permutations S. It would then follow that G is isomorphic to $\phi[S]$ and $\phi[S]$ is a group of permutations.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's it. Go on to section 9:)

Comment: What are you talking about? I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: I think he means that you are right in feeling that it is automatic in the assumptions and there is no extra need for the justification. Fraleigh probably said this just for reinforcing the definition.

Answer (score 1):

For $\phi$ to be an isomorphism, its inverse mapping $\phi^{-1}\colon \phi[G]\to G$ -- which clearly exists in the set-theoretic sense, i.e. as a mapping between elements -- must be a homomorphism too. And that's not self-evident, so that's the part that requires a proof.

(I don't have the book with me now, and I don't remember whether such a statement was proven earlier in the book, in which case for this theorem only a reference would suffice.)